# Durable power adapter for HP laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hp-pavilion

I'm on my third power adapter for my HP Pavilion dv4-1435dx in less than one year. I'm not abusing them. I used Mac laptops for 10 years (before needing to switch to a PC) without a problem.

I tried a Targus universal power adapter, but it wouldn't charge my PC, it worked fine on another laptop http://www.targus.com/us/product_details.aspx?sku=APA6911US

Any suggestion for a more durable and reliable power adapter?

Comment: If the power adapters are lasting < 1 year, wouldn't the official HP power adapters have some sort of warranty? Or have all these replacements been warranty replacements?

Comment: The first was HP brand that came with the machine, the replacement was a cheap "PWR+" brand from Amazon. I still need to buy a third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to find a power adapter with a good strain relief on the DC section of the adapter. The straight strain relief of the HP's adapters is not really good, a 90 degrees bend like Lenovo's adapter seem to last longer because the DC wire will not be bent during the transport.

Also, try not to bend the strain relief when storing the adapter, make a loose loop with the wire instead of a square angle, this will prolong the life of the wire when it's used with a straight strain relief

HP straight strain relief (The wire is bent a lot)

[image: Square angle of HP adapter]

Lenovo 90 degrees strain relief (a lot better)

[image: Lenovo adapter]